# Why should I use getcomponent?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I have already referred the animator by using the statement,

```
       Animator anim;
```

But,What is the use of getcomponent in awake() function.What happens without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Animator anim;` is just a empty reference. If you want to actually access the `Animator` script attached to the object, you'll have to use `GetComponent<Animator>()` and assign it to `anim`.

Your first sentence is incorrect `Animator anim;` does not refer to anything. It's simply a placeholder for referencing an `Animator` object. It doesn't point to anything unless you tell it what to point to.

Answer (score 1):

if you make a public variable like

```
public Animator anim;
```

in a monobehavior script, outside any method, you can drag and drop a gameobject with animator component in inspector when you add this script to a gameobject. it will automatically get the Animator component from the dropped gameobject.

But if you already have a reference to the desired gameobject(g) with a Animator component, you can get a reference to it by

```
anim= g.GetComponent<Animator>();
```